# executing rawquery with WHERE Clause from another Activity to recieve Table Values

Tags: android

I am having a problem in SQLiteDatabase. I want to access the database table created in one Activity from another Activity.However when I use WHERE clause the query is not executing. 
I am referring sambleDB from CropInfoListclass.

These are some codes.

```
String[] item = {getIntent().getExtras().getString("item")};

Cursor c = CropInfoList.sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TableName +" WHERE "+ name +"=?", item);

String Name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
String Type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
```

Comment: What error you are getting in your logcat?

Comment: I can guess your unmentioned problem by this way. Did you mention the dbname.close()(dbname means your database name)inside of your previous activity. If yes then please call opendatabase again.? Or else please tell me what's the error points out in logcat?If you don't have the logcat please add it by in eclipse windows->showview->Logcat is available

Comment: @Akshay Yes you got it right, I had closed the database name. And when i used 

String Name = c.getString(0); 
It started working... Thank you.